# What is the best method to update a components data from a data change in another component? Angular 2

Tags: angular, lifecycle

So basically, I have made a generic component which simply displays an objects data. The data is sent via a button click. So the generic component reads the data during the OnInit life cycle hook which looks like this.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.settingsService.getAllSettings().responseData()
        .subscribe(settingsStream => { this.settingsList = settingsStream.result }, (err) => {
            // Error Messages
        },
        () => {
            // Complete Messages
            this.currentSetting = this.settingsList
                .findIndex(setting => setting.configurationName === this.settingsService.selectedSetting.selectConfig);
        })
}
```

Once it has found the configuration name and matches it to the selected name. It displays the correct value in the template like so.

```
<input size="150" [value]="settingsList[currentSetting].configurationName" [(ngModel)]="settingsList[currentSetting].configurationName">
```

However the generic components data can be changed via a button click. However because the generic component only reads the data from during the OnInit it does not change the data it displays. I have tried using the onChanges and doCheck lifecycle hook however they do not allow me to alter the data as it is constantly looking for changes.

This is my method in the template which activates and displays the component from a button click

```
      <div *ngFor="let settings of settingsList">
<button class="btn btn-secondary"  
(click)="changeSection(settings.configurationName)" 
(click)="domElement='Generic'"> {{settings.configurationName}} </button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showNewConfig">
<new-config> </new-config>
```

I had this previously working with separate components however this seems inefficient and a duplication of code.

All help would be greatly appreciated many thanks!

Comment: You have (click) twice (click)="changeSection(settings.configurationName)" 
(click)="domElement='Generic'"

Comment: @Vega as far as I am aware this should not affect the working of the generic component updating on a data change

Comment: I didn't say that's the issue. I pointed out some incoherent code

Comment: @Vega is there a way to have one click event binding to two things?

Comment: You cannot have two (click) events, only one would be fired

Comment: If you wish to chain them, put (click)= "method1(); method2()"

Comment: Or `(click)=method1()`, then `method1{method2(); method3(); //anything else}`

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstood what you are looking for, but I cannot put this in a comment:

```
ngOnInit(){
      loadData()
    }

loadData(){
   this.settingsService.getAllSettings().responseData().....
}

<button (click)="loadData()">Load</button>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?